# Grep values from nethog and netperf

Tags: linux, networking, awk, grep

I need to monitor the network activities of a process and the bandwidth of the connection. So I decided to use `nethog` and `netperf` combine with `grep` and `awk` to write the values to a file.

`nethog` command: `nethogs -t  eth0 | grep firefox | awk '{ print $3 }'` (I want to take the upload/download speed). **The 1st problem** is that command doesn't print anything.

More detail:
command: `nethogs -t  eth0 | grep firefox` output:

```
usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000  0.338867    0.239063
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.543555    0.274219
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.794531    0.489844
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.794531    0.489844
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 0.749023    0.589844
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 1.30098 3.47617
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 1.90449 8.0127
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 5.31641 25.0033
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bi�)/4956/1000 8.60762 42.0176
```

I want the two values at the bottom right. But as you can see the output ain't consistent (the space), add `| awk '{print $3}'` most of the time return nothing. And I can't fix this.

`netperf` command: `netperf -H 192.168.1.10` and the output is:

```
Recv   Send    Send                          
Socket Socket  Message  Elapsed              
Size   Size    Size     Time     Throughput  
bytes  bytes   bytes    secs.    10^6bits/sec  

524288 524288 262144    10.00    **718.62**
```

I want to print the value on the bottom right but have no idea how to. That's the **2nd problem**

Can you guys help me out? Any ideas will be appreciated!